# Field initialization in a sub-class happens after constructor finishes in the parent class, in javascript. Is this by design?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

It is easier to show than to describe it. Here is the code

```
let ns = {};

ns.A = class {
    constructor() { 
        this.Virtual();
    }   

    Virtual() {
    }
};

ns.B = class extends ns.A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        alert(this.Field);
    }

    Field = 0;  

    Virtual() {
        this.Field = 123;
    }
}
```

The `alert()` says that `this.Field` equals 0. That is, field initialization in the B class is performed after the A constructor finishes. Is this "by design" in Javascript?

If I put the `Field` in the prototype of the B class, then everything works OK, just like in any other language. For example

```
let ns = {};

ns.A = class {
    constructor() { 
        this.Virtual();
    }   

    Virtual() {
    }
};

ns.B = class extends ns.A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        alert(this.Field);
    }

    //Field = 0;    

    Virtual() {
        this.Field = 123;
    }
}

ns.B.prototype.Field;
```

Sorry to bother you here with this, but I don't know where is the right place to report this issue.

Comment: Yes, this is by design (they are evaluated at the end of the `super()` call, where `this` has been initialised to the instance created by the parent constructor) - but it is *always* a bad idea (not only in JavaScript) to call virtual methods from a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#execution-of-initializer-expressions:

> When field initializers are evaluated...
>
> Base class: At the beginning of the constructor execution...
>
> Derived class: Right after super() returns...

Illustration:

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        console.log('A constructor start');
        this.Virtual();
        console.log('A constructor end');
    }

    Field = (() => { console.log('A field init'); return 1})()

    Virtual() {
    }
};

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        console.log('B constructor start')
        super();
        console.log('B constructor end')
    }

    Field = (() => { console.log('B field init'); return 2})()

    Virtual() {
        console.log('B virtual')
        this.Field = 123;
    }
};

console.log(new B())
```

That is, in your code, `Field = 0` happens after `this.Field = 123`, thus overwriting it. The order of declarations doesn't matter.

If you have issues with this behaviour and wish to discuss it, https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/issues would be the right place.